# How to automate and show calculation steps using a custom function formula

Tags: r, function

I have this function calculating a formula:

```
my_formula <- function(x, y, z = 195.084){
  output = case_when(
    y == "A" ~ x/z * 300.05,
    y == "B" ~ x/z * 397.28,
    .default = x
  )
  return(output)
}
```

and this data frame on which the function should be applied:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, ppm = c(0.73, 0.807), material = c("A", 
"B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))

  id   ppm material
1  1 0.730        A
2  2 0.807        B
```

I do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ppm_calculated = my_formula(ppm, material))
```

and I get:

```
     id   ppm material ppm_calculated
  <int> <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
1     1 0.730 A                  1.12
2     2 0.807 B                  1.64
```

I would like to add a new column that shows the calculation steps for each material, like:

```
     id   ppm material ppm_calculated calculation             
  <int> <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <chr>                   
1     1 0.730 A                  1.12 0.730 / 300.05 * 195.084
2     2 0.807 B                  1.64 0.807 / 397.28 * 195.084
```

I can do this with:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(ppm_calculated = my_formula(ppm, material)) %>% 
   mutate(calculation = case_when(
    material == "A" ~ sprintf("%.3f / 300.05 * 195.084", ppm),
    material == "B" ~ sprintf("%.3f / 397.28 * 195.084", ppm),
    .default = as.character(ppm)
  ))
```

But I want to do it automatically.

Comment: If you are asking how to get the body of the function given the inputs and outputs then that is undecidable but if we can assume a certain form for the body then it may be possible.  Please clarify.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you for your reply. I had difficulties to express what I want. The body of the function will always do the same calculation conditional on material. material is either A then division by 300.05 or B then division by 397.28. And material is a column with only the values A or B in the df. z is always the same e..g. 195.084 and x is the value in a column in df (in this example it is column ppm). I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `substitute`:

```
my_formula <- function(x, y, z = 195.084){
    fm <- function(x, y, z){
        a <- substitute(x/z * y, list(x = x, y = y, z = z))
        data.frame(list(value=a), calculation = deparse1(a))
    }
    
    b <- Map(fm, x, c(A = 300.05, B = 397.28)[y], z)
    do.call(rbind, b)
}

with(df, my_formula(ppm, material))
    value            calculation
1 1.12278  0.73/195.084 * 300.05
2 1.64342 0.807/195.084 * 397.28
```

---

The function works within mutate as well:

```
df %>%
  mutate(my_formula(ppm, material))
  id   ppm material   value            calculation
1  1 0.730        A 1.12278  0.73/195.084 * 300.05
2  2 0.807        B 1.64342 0.807/195.084 * 397.28
```

---

#### Edit:

If you could use `strings` then simply do:

```
my_formula <- function(x, y, z = 195.084){
    y <- c(A = 300.05, B = 397.28)[y]
    data.frame(value = x / z * y, calc = paste(x, '/', z, '*',y))
}
with(df, my_formula(ppm, material))
    value                     calc
A 1.12278  0.73 / 195.084 * 300.05
B 1.64342 0.807 / 195.084 * 397.28
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just have your function return both in a data frame and the unnest the data frame.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_formula <- function(x, y, z = 195.084){
  calc = case_when(
    y == "A" ~ sprintf("%.3f / 300.05 * %.3f", x, z), 
    y == "B" ~ sprintf("%.3f / 397.28 * %.3f", x, z)
  )
  output = case_when(
    y == "A" ~ x/z * 300.05,
    y == "B" ~ x/z * 397.28,
    .default = x
  )
  output <- data.frame(calculated = output, calculation = calc)
  return(output)
}

df <- structure(list(id = 1:2, ppm = c(0.73, 0.807), 
                     material = c("A", "B")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))

df %>% 
  mutate(res = my_formula(ppm, material)) %>% 
  unnest(res)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>      id   ppm material calculated calculation             
#>   <int> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>                   
#> 1     1 0.73  A              1.12 0.730 / 300.05 * 195.084
#> 2     2 0.807 B              1.64 0.807 / 397.28 * 195.084
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version using `substitute`, which additionally allows you to pass the unquoted function body as an argument, and allows you to specify the calculation *or* the result:

```r
my_formula <- function(x, y, z = 195.084, f = x/z * y, formula = FALSE) {
  
  y <- case_when(y == "A" ~ 300.05, 
                 y == "B" ~ 397.28, 
                 .default = 1/z)
  
  f <- substitute(f)
  
  calc <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    do.call("substitute", list(expr = f, env = list(x = x[i], y = y[i], z = z)))
    })
  
  if(formula) sapply(calc, deparse) else sapply(calc, eval)
}
```

Testing

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ppm_calculated = my_formula(ppm, material),
         calculation = my_formula(ppm, material, formula = TRUE))
#>   id   ppm material ppm_calculated            calculation
#> 1  1 0.730        A        1.12278  0.73/195.084 * 300.05
#> 2  2 0.807        B        1.64342 0.807/195.084 * 397.28
```